# In Android Studio, how to specify runtime user ID (sharedUserId="android.uid.system") for a JUnit test

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, junit5

When using JUnit5 to run tests that require access to hidden/internal Android APIs, the tests need to run with elevated privilege. In the app's manifest the following entry would normally be declared **android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"**

Is it possible to configure the unit tests to execute with such elevated privilege?